# Django model id has gaps

Tags: django

I am have a Django 1.7rc project running on multiple app servers and a MySQL.

I have noticed the primary key of a model has gaps, eg, from 10001 jumps to 10003, 10011 jumps to 10014. I cannot figure out why, there is no code to delete the records directly, however it could be cascade deleted, which I will investigate further.

```
    order = Order(cart=cart)
    order.billing_address = billing_address
    order.payment = payment
    order.account = account
    order.user_uuid = account.get('uuid')
    order.save()
```

Thought I would ask here if this is normal on a multiple app server setup?

Answer (score 1):

Gaps in a primary key are normal (unless you're using a misconfigured SQLite table, which does not use a monotonic PK by default) and help to maintain referential integrity. Having said that, they are usually only caused by deletions or updates within the table, cascaded or otherwise. Verify that you have no code which may delete or update the PK in that table, directly or indirectly.