# when i delete rows from my database the primary key increases

Tags: django, django-1.8

I tried deleting the data from my table from Django administration (I use default database), but the primary key keeps on increasing, i.e I had two instances in my table, I deleted them, and added a new one, so shouldn't the primary key be 1, but it becomes zero. how do I make it 1 again?
Should I auto increment?

Comment: That's how pretty much all databases work. Is there any specific reason you want to reset the auto increment sequence? If not, just leave it be.

Comment: I deleted all the row to add a new one, so to again start pk from 1 , I wanted a solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django model id has gaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25374863/django-model-id-has-gaps)

Comment: You really should explain why you want to do this.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't do anything with the primary key. If it's an auto-incremented id, it will always increase, even if you delete one row or all rows from the table.

Comment: i want to reset it, i mean the primary key

Comment: The only way to do it is in raw SQL:

 
python manage.py dbshell
mysql> ALTER TABLE <table_name> AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;

Comment: isnt the default like, sqlite

Comment: But it's really bad idea, and I don't recommend to do it.